# integer solutions to $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2 = w^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Is there a way to find *all* integer primitive solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2 = w^2$? i.e., is there a parametrization which covers all the possible solutions?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Yes, but how to parametrize them all?

Comment: Put y=z=w=0 or z=w=0

Comment: what about those where all the variables are non-zero?

Comment: Does my answer (below) not suffice? If it does, please consider accepting it; if it doesn't, please clarify what additional information you need.

Answer (score 2):

**All natural numbers are the sum of four squares.** See [Lagrange's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem). So all perfect squares meet the property in question; i.e., $w\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yes, I know about Lagrange's 4 squares theorem, but my question is whether there is any parametrization which covers all the solutions!

Comment: Yes: *w* $\in$ **Z**

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I was hoping to know something more on the *shape* of the solutions! Something along the lines of the parametrization for the primitive Pythagorean quadruples, as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple

Comment: also, I'm not sure if the parametrization $w \in \mathbb{Z}$ works, if I'm only interested in *primitive* solutions.

Comment: @Lucian But if instead of integers, natural numbers is given then what will be the solutions

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria That doesn't matter, as we're only concerned with squares. My problem is that there might be some $w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that all the solutions to $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2 = w^2$ are not primitive.

Comment: @user134641: All prime *w* meet that condition. If $\gcd(x,y,z,t)=d\neq1$, then $d|w$

Comment: @Lucian which condition? Can you refer me to a proof?

Comment: If $\gcd(x,y,z,t)=d\neq1$, then $d|w$. So *w* is prime.

Comment: @Lucian But what if $w$ is not prime? Is there always a primitive solution?

Comment: If *w* is composite, then it has at least *one* non-primitive solution. And if it is a prime, then it has *only* primitive solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Bradley’s [excellent paper on equal sums of squares](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620159) gives the complete parameterization of the equation
$$
  x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = y_1^2
$$
as
\begin{align}
   x_1 &= (uz+vy+wz)^2 -m^2(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-u^2-v^2-w^2) \\
   x_2 &= 2m(um^2+uz^2+xvm-ywm+xwz+yvz)  \\
   x_3 &= 2m(vm^2+vy^2+zwm-xum+zuy+xwy)  \\
   x_4 &= 2m(wm^2+wx^2+yum-zvm+yvx+zux)  \\
   y_1 &= (uz+vy+wz)^2 +m^2(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+u^2+v^2+w^2),
\end{align}
with the option of multiplying all terms by a common factor $l$. Note that each term is a homogeneous quartic expression in the seven [integer] parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation:

$X^2+Y^2+Z^2+Q^2=R^2$

We can write the solution:

$X=2p^2+2(a+b+t)ps+(ab+at+bt)s^2$

$Y=2p^2+2(b+t-a)ps+(bt-a^2)s^2$

$Z=2p^2+2(a+t-b)ps+(at-b^2)s^2$

$Q=2p^2+2(a+b-t)ps+(ab-t^2)s^2$

$R=4p^2+2(a+b+t)ps+(a^2+b^2+t^2)s^2$

And more:

$X=-2p^2+2(a+b+t)ps+(4a^2+4b^2+4t^2-ab-at-bt)s^2$

$Y=-2p^2+2(b+t-5a)ps+(a^2-4a(b+t)+4b^2+4t^2-bt)s^2$

$Z=-2p^2+2(t+a-5b)ps+(b^2-4b(a+t)+4a^2+4t^2-at)s^2$

$Q=-2p^2+2(a+b-5t)ps+(t^2-4t(a+b)+4a^2+4b^2-ab)s^2$

$R=4p^2+2(a+b+t)ps+(7a^2+7b^2+7t^2-4ab-4at-4bt)s^2$

$a,b,t,p,s$ - integers asked us.