# Is sum of square of primes a square of prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

I would like to know if it has been proved that :

- There are no $a$, $b$ and $c$, all prime numbers, such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
- There are no $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, all prime numbers, such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2$
- There are no $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$, all prime numbers, such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = e^2$

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: For the first, we must have $a=2$ or $b=2$.

Comment: But there is no Pythagorean triplets (a, b, c) with $a = 2$ or $b = 2$.

Comment: Yes, thats why the first one is trivial.

Comment: But why we must have $a = 2$ or $b = 2$ ?

Comment: For the second one must be $3$. And one can work out the third statement similarly to the first.

Comment: @LucasWillems, if $a$ and $b$ are both odd then $a^2+b^2$ is even and so $c$ is even...

Comment: @lhf, thanks. You are right.

Comment: because a and b are both odd that holds for all prime numbers except 2! so c will be even which could hold only for 2 which is not possible

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you explain a little bit ?

Comment: For the second: If $a$ is not divisible by $3$, then $a^2=1\pmod{3}$. For the third: If $a,b,c,d$ are all odd, then $d$ is even.

Comment: Need formula to use. For example this.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762769/integer-solutions-to-x2y2z2t2-w2/762907#762907

Comment: @QuangHoang, ok. But does that prove the second and the third ? For the second, maybe $a = 3$. No ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the (full) solution is longer than a comment. So here it goes.

---

Suppose that for $a,b,c,d$ primes,
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$$
Obviously $d=3$ is not a solution. That implies
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}.$$
So exact two of $a,b,c$ are equal to $3$. We are left to solve
$$d^2-a^2=(d-a)(d+a)=18.$$
But $d-a$ and $d+a$ are of the same parity and $18$ cannot be factorized into such a product.

---

For the third equations, note that $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ if $n$ is odd. Thus if 
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=e^2,$$
then exactly $3$ of $a,b,c,d$ are $2$. We are left to solve
$$(e-d)(e+d)=12=6\cdot 2.$$
It follows that $e+d=6$, and $e-d=2$. That means $e=4$, not a prime.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is nearly the same proof I found on my own.